# Matplotlib's 'annotate' not positioning text correctly in PDFs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

Matplotlib' `annotate` seems to fail to position text correctly when rendered to PDF.

For example, if I attempt to center a [▲ character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b4/index.htm) at the location of a tick on an axis with

```
fig.ax.annotate('▲',(a_tic_loc, x_axis_loc), ha='center', va='top')
```

instead of getting the expected and correct

[image]

as I do in when rendered to PNG I get

[image]

in my PDF (on OS X 10.10; Python 2.7.6; Matplotlib 1.4.2).

Is this a known bug? Is there a reliable workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Use latex:

```
import pylab as pl
fig, ax = pl.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
ann = ax.annotate(r'$\blacktriangle$',(0.2, 0.0), ha='center', va='top', size=40)
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: That seems to work (though `\blacktriangle` seems to be `BLACK UP-POINTING TRIANGLE` rather than `BLACK UP-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE`; is there LaTeX for that?). Is a tweak like this the only solution: is this a (known) bug in matplotlib or the PDF renderer?

Comment: I've got a lot of characters I used to annotate, not just the triangle (which is an example), and many are not in LaTeX character sets.